# Disable certain items in kendo multiselect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo multiselect in an mvc application.

```
                 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(a => a.Roles)
                              .Value(Model.SelectedRoles)
                              .DataValueField("Id")
                              .DataTextField("RoleName")
                              .Placeholder("")
                              .HtmlAttributes(new { required = "" })
                              .DataSource(source =>
                              {
                                  source.Read(read => read.Action("GetRoles", "UserManagement"));
                              }))
```

It gets populated with the GetRoles method like so:

```
public List<RoleViewModel> GetRoles()
    {
        var roles = _context.Roles.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        var roleList = new List<RoleViewModel>();

        foreach(var role in roles)
        {
            roleList.Add(new RoleViewModel
            {
                Id = role.Id,
                RoleName = role.Name
            });
        }

        return roleList;
    }
```

Now I'm trying to disable certain items inside the list how would I go about to do that?

I was thinking if I could add maybe a bool ItemStatus in my RoleViewModel and set that status to true/false based on some conditions but I have no idea how I would go about and actually apply it to the multiselect so that said items with the ItemStatus set to false would be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find below mention code in reference link.
[Check this link](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/disable-multiselect-items)

There are property of unselectableItem: true and unselectableItem: false which can help.

Comment: "To prevent the selection, cancel the select event. To prevent the drop-down list from closing, set the autoClose property."
What a horrible approach :/

Answer (score 0):

Add an indicator to your ViewModel to disable your multi select item.

```
public class RoleViewModel 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string RoleName { get; set; } 
    public bool Disabled { get; set; } 
}
```

Update your Action metod to specify Disabled items

```
public List<RoleViewModel> GetRoles()
{
    var roles = _context.Roles.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    var roleList = new List<RoleViewModel>();

    foreach(var role in roles)
    {
        roleList.Add(new RoleViewModel
        {
            Id = role.Id,
            RoleName = role.Name,
            Disabled = **Your Condition**
        });
    }

    return roleList;
}
```

Modify your View as below

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(a => a.Roles)
                          .Value(Model.SelectedRoles)
                          .Events(x => x.Select("onRolesSelect"))
                          .ItemTemplateId("rolestemplate")
                          .DataValueField("Id")
                          .DataTextField("RoleName")
                          .Placeholder("")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { required = "" })
                          .DataSource(source =>
                          {
                              source.Read(read => read.Action("GetRoles", "UserManagement"));
                          }))

<script id="rolestemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
                                    <span class="#: Disabled ? 'k-state-disabled': ''#">
                                     #: Text #
                                    </span>
                                </script>
```

In your Javascript add below function

```
function onRolesSelect(e) {
        if (e.dataItem.Disabled) {
            //prevent selection by cancelling the event
            e.preventDefault();
            this.setOptions({ autoClose: false });
        }
        else {
            this.setOptions({ autoClose: true });
        }
    };
```

Hope this helps.